# UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY issue

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I am trying to make this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(fk_player_id) count FROM wr_year WHERE fk_player_id=$currplayer AND year=2013");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

if($row['count'] == 0){
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO wr_year (fk_player_id, year, points) VALUES ($currplayer, 2013, $points)");
} else {
   mysql_query("UPDATE wr_year SET points=points+$points WHERE fk_player_id=$currplayer AND year=2013");
}
```

Into this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO wr_year (fk_player_id, year, points) VALUES ($currplayer, 2013, $points)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE points=points+$points");
```

But this ain working? How do I ensure that it checks ON DUPLICATE only on fk_player_id and year, and can it be done?

Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: and what u will do with this `WHERE fk_player_id=$currplayer` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY` checks for index violations to see if it should insert or update, so you'll need to first create a unique index on the two columns you want to check;

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uix_wr_year ON wr_year (fk_player_id, year);
```

After that, it will instead update if the same fk_player_id/year combination already exists in the table.

Comment: Just did the job... Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

use the `VALUES` function.

try this

```
     INSERT INTO wr_year (fk_player_id, year, points) VALUES ($currplayer, 2013, $points)
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE points= VALUES(points+$points)
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html